# Resize window after taskbar hidden

Tags: autohotkey

Below hotkey script hides/displays taskbar when lWin&H is keyed :

```
LWin & h::

if toggle := !toggle

{

WinHide ahk_class Shell_TrayWnd

WinHide Start ahk_class Button

}

else

{

WinShow ahk_class Shell_TrayWnd

WinShow Start ahk_class Button

}
return
```

Script is taken from a comment at http://lifehacker.com/taskbar-control-hides-and-unhides-the-windows-taskbar-w-1573974951

But when the taskbar is hidden the space which occupied the taskbar is unusable : windows do not drag to this area, newly opened program do not occupy this space.

Can script be modified so that when taskbar is hidden the entire screen area is usable ?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/654170/how-to-toggle-the-auto-hide-status-of-the-windows-taskbar::

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way that sets the work area to include the taskbar space to.

```
LWin & h::
if toggle := !toggle
{
    WinHide ahk_class Shell_TrayWnd
    WinHide Start ahk_class Button
    SysGet, Mon, Monitor
    SetWorkArea(MonLeft, MonTop, MonRight, MonBottom)
}
else
{
    WinShow ahk_class Shell_TrayWnd
    WinShow Start ahk_class Button
    SysGet, Mon, MonitorWorkArea
    SetWorkArea(MonLeft, MonTop, MonRight, MonBottom)
}
return

SetWorkArea(left,top,right,bottom)  ; set main monitor work area ; windows are not resized!
{
    VarSetCapacity(area, 16)
    NumPut(left,  area, 0, "UInt") ; left
    NumPut(top,   area, 4, "UInt") ; top
    NumPut(right, area, 8, "UInt") ; right
    NumPut(bottom,area,12, "UInt") ; bottom
    DllCall("SystemParametersInfo", "UInt", 0x2F, "UInt", 0, "UPtr", &area, "UInt", 0) ; SPI_SETWORKAREA
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: thanks but when I hide the taskbar using script the area that the taskbar occupies is not usable by other programs.

Comment: To bad! Works just fine for me on win7 with ahk 1.1+ 32 bit unicode

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using autohotkey I use this utility :

http://www.itsamples.com/taskbar-hider.html

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work (just tested on Windows7) :

```
   lWin & h::

;#NoEnv

#NoTrayIcon

;#SingleInstance force

DetectHiddenWindows, Off   ;for IfWinExist

VarSetCapacity( APPBARDATA, 36, 0 )

;------------------------------------------------------------

; Fetch current hidden/showing status



IfWinNotExist, ahk_class Shell_TrayWnd

  TaskbarAndStartToggleState = 0     ;Currently [color=darkred]hidden[/color] (not showing)

Else

  TaskbarAndStartToggleState = 1     ;Currently [color=darkred]non-hidden[/color] (showing)

;------------------------------------------------------------

Gosub +z   ;Toggle the taskbar/SM state

;------------------------------------------------------------

Exit

;------------------------------------------------------------

+z::

 TaskbarAndStartToggleState := Func(TaskbarAndStartToggleState)

Return



Func(TaskbarAndStartToggleState)

{

   Global APPBARDATA



   If TaskbarAndStartToggleState = 0

   {

      NumPut( (ABS_ALWAYSONTOP := 0x2), APPBARDATA, 32, "UInt" )           ;Enable "Always on top" [color=darkred](& disable auto-hide)[/color]

      DllCall( "Shell32.dll\SHAppBarMessage", "UInt", ( ABM_SETSTATE := 0xA ), "UInt", &APPBARDATA )



      WinShow ahk_class Shell_TrayWnd

      Return 1            ;Now showing

   }



   If TaskbarAndStartToggleState = 1

   {

      NumPut( ( ABS_AUTOHIDE := 0x1 ), APPBARDATA, 32, "UInt" )            ;Disable "Always on top" [color=darkred](& enable auto-hide to hide Start button)[/color]

      DllCall( "Shell32.dll\SHAppBarMessage", "UInt", ( ABM_SETSTATE := 0xA ), "UInt", &APPBARDATA )



      WinHide ahk_class Shell_TrayWnd

      ;WinHide ahk_class Shell_TrayWnd   ;[color=darkred]don't need this 2nd one?[/color]

      Return 0            ;Now hidden

   }

}

return
```

Slightly modified from :

http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/25932-trying-to-toggle-autohide-taskbar-with-keystroke-in-vista/page-2

Update : This script causes unexpected behavior when using multiple desktops. The taskbar is hidden but when toggle to restore just windows icon is display. Hiding the taskbar and unhiding the taskbar in taskbar properties appears to fix this, but this makes the script unusable if using multiple desktops.